# Why does Rey leave her speeder unattended?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, vehicles

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey often leaves her speeder completely unattended. Why is this? Thievery appears to be very common on Jakku.

Comment: Good question, but I'm more concerned as to why she left BB-8 unattended to chase after Finn, only moments after a couple of thieves tried to put BB-8 in a sack.

Comment: @Praxis - It's a very very small town. I'm assuming she knows precisely how many goons Unkar has. Evidently that number is two.

Comment: Did you see what she did to the guys who tried to kidnap BB-8?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the new [*Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) book, [Rey's speeder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYODi.jpg) is booby-trapped with a special circuit which [electrifies the chassis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U4ZYOBzEEs) to deter any would-be thieves.

[image: Part of a cut-away drawing of Rey's speeder with callouts for various components. And obviously not hand-drawn box highlights "Wire electrifies chassis to keep thieves away" which points to a small wire at the back of the pod just beside the engines]

It also features a fingerprint scanner to ensure that only she is able to use it.

[image: Another snippet of the book reads "Scavenger safeguards: Light-fingered scavengers are a fact of life on Jakku, and Rey knows that without her speeder she'd be even more trapped than she already is, unable to travel between the Starship Graveyard, her makeshift homestead, and Niima Outpost. Her speeder won't power up without a fingerprint scan, and she can electrify the chassis to give a powerful jolt to anyone who touches it while she's away."]

The factbook [*Rey's Survival Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rey%27s_Survival_Guide) also offers the following info. In short, even if someone managed to steal her speeder, they'd probably crash it within seconds. On top of that, Unkar has told the local low-lives to leave her ride alone.

[image: Image of text in a hand-written font: "My speeder's not easy to pilot. It's top-heavy and if you're not careful, it'll roll. That's fine with me-I know what I'm doing, and if anyone steals my baby they won't get far. The other scavengers don't mess with my ride. One reason is because Unkar's told them not to-not because he likes me but because I bring in the most valuable stuff. The other reason is that I programmed a fingerprint scanner for my speeder. Without that, it won't power up. You could hot-wire it but I intentionally left a wire loose. When I'm exploring a wreck, I attach that wire to the hull and it electrifies the whole thing. It's not enough to kill someone but it will definitely make them think twice about doing that again."]

Comment: Excellent answer, in spite of the fact that your red box is unlikely to be free-hand...

Comment: @Praxis - No, but I did squeeze in a Robocop joke, so I'm still pretty pleased with myself.

Comment: If only there were some sort of material which could act as a sort of insulator